# Ubuntu 18.04 libnss3-1d:i386 Install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, libraries

I'm trying to install LPCXpresso v8.2.2 on my new Ubuntu 18.04 (amd64 of course) laptop.
Following the read me I issue the command

> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxtst6:i386 libpangox
>   1.0-0:i386 \
>                libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 \
>               libncurses5:i386 libudev1:i386 libusb-1.0:i386 libusb-0.1:i386 \
>               gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libnss3-1d:i386

In order to install i386 compatible libraries.
Here's the output

> Building dependency tree           Reading state information...
>   Done
>   Note, selecting 'libusb-1.0-0:i386' for regex 'libusb-1.0'
>
> Note, selecting 'libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386' for regex 'libusb-1.0'
>
> Note, selecting 'libusb-1.0-doc:i386' for regex 'libusb-1.0'
>
> Note, selecting 'libusb-1.0-doc' instead of 'libusb-1.0-doc:i386'
>
> Note, selecting 'libusb-0.1-4:i386' for regex 'libusb-0.1'
>
> Package libnss3-1d:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>       is only available from another source

When then I try to execute the installer with

> sudo ./Installer_LPCXpresso_8.2.2_650_Linux-x86

Simply nothing happens.
Has anyone already had similar issues?

Comment: Did you forgot to run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` followed by `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I run that but i got same output for libnss3-1d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libnss3-1d) I see that `libnss3-1d` package is not available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

It seems to be renamed to `libnss3`. Install 32-bit version of it with

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3:i386
```

and continue.

---

I'm not familiar with these tools, but you can also try [MCUXpresso](https://www.nxp.com/support/developer-resources/software-development-tools/mcuxpresso-software-and-tools:MCUXPRESSO) (plus see [installation guide](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/quick-reference-guide/MCUXpresso_IDE_Installation_Guide.pdf)).